# Visual Studio 2010 64bit Library Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, windows-7-x64

Dear StackOverFlow experts, 
I have searched and searched for a solution to this problem but have not found an answer.  I have found people with similar questions but not an answer.  I humbly ask for your forgiveness if I have overlooked a solution.  With this I ask you to please consider my submission.

I have a simple test code for OpenCV 2.4.11 in Visual Studio 2010 x64

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\types_c.h>
using namespace cv;

int main(){

IplImage* img=cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\Russ\\Pictures\\3-7-15\\_DSC8489.jpg"); //change the name

       cvNamedWindow("Example1",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );

cvShowImage("Example1",img);

cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvDestroyWindow( "Example1");

return 0;

}
```

When I Build this I get an error

C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory

All of the opencv includes are included in my properties path as are my libraries for OpenCV.  When I open the types_c.h file I see the following

```
/*M///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  IMPORTANT: READ BEFORE DOWNLOADING, COPYING, INSTALLING OR USING.
//
//  By downloading, copying, installing or using the software you agree to this license.
//  If you do not agree to this license, do not download, install,
//  copy or use the software.
//
//
//                          License Agreement
//                For Open Source Computer Vision Library
//
//M*/

#ifndef __OPENCV_CORE_TYPES_H__
#define __OPENCV_CORE_TYPES_H_
#if !defined _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE && defined _MSC_VER
#  if _MSC_VER > 1300
#    define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /* to avoid multiple Visual  Studio 2005 warnings  */
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef SKIP_INCLUDES
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>

#if !defined _MSC_VER && !defined  __BORLANDC__
#  include <stdint.h>
#endif

#...
```

Since assert.h is used for debugging, I decided to comment out the assert.h line.  When I Build the code again I got this error.

C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(56): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory

Clearly something is not set properly for Visual Studio 2010 as it can not find these libraries.  Can someone tell how to fix this problem in Visual Studio 2010 x64.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right click the project in VS, select "Properties" and select "VC++ Directories" on the left hand side menu. What do you see under "Include directories"?

Comment: Mewa Thanks for responding...  The VC++ Directories   Include Directories have C:\opencv\build\include;C:\opencv\build\include\opencv;C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2;$(IncludePath)

Comment: I should add that I am able to run this code successfully on Visual Studio 2013 Community but for some reason I can not get it to run on Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: Try appending (add a `;` after everything you already have) `$(VCInstallDir)include` in the "Include directories" list. Alternatively, go to "Include directories" and select "edit". Navigate to your install directory manually - for me this is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include. That include folder seems to have everything that you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you only need to include `opencv2/opencv.hpp` to make it work.

Also, since you're using C++, it's strongly recommended to use OpenCV's C++ API over deprecated C API. The code will be like:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Russ\\Pictures\\3-7-15\\_DSC8489.jpg");

    cv::namedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Example1", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::destroyWindow("Example1");

    return 0;
}
```

**Updated:**
If you still encounter with problems, you should follow [this post](http://www.anlak.com/2012/10/using-opencv-2-4-x-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial.html) to setup OpenCV correctly with VS.

Comment: Hello Herohuyongtao,   I tried your suggestion.  There was no change in the error.  There is the log 1>------ Build started: Project: OpenCVTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 4/10/2015 8:46:31 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "x64\Debug\OpenCVTest.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Main.cpp
1>C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'assert.h': No such file or directory
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.60
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @thiirane You should, then, follow [this post](http://www.anlak.com/2012/10/using-opencv-2-4-x-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial.html) to setup OpenCV correctly with VS.

Comment: Sir, I know you are trying to help. Very respectfully..I have done this over and over.  As I have stated, I have done a clean install of Visual Studio 2013 Community and was able to get it to work so I feel confident that OpenCV is installed correctly.  The libraries that Visual Studio 2010 is looking for are not OpenCV libraries.  I need to be able to change Visual Studio 2010 path (somewhere) to point to the C++ libraries assert.h, stdlib.h...etc... Where do these libraries reside? Are these an SDK libraries?